# Looking for Server Side Rendering using VUEJS having ASPX page and site hosting on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, vuejs2, iis-7, server-side-rendering, asp-net-core-spa-services

We have our existing pages in ASPX and site is hosted on IIS7 server.
We are looking for revamping/design the pages in VUEJS 2.0.

We are able to get VueJS code integrated with existing ASPX pages by getting build.js generated (production) and referring the same on ASPX page and page will be having the Target element. This all is client side rendering.
Now, we want the same in SSR. That mean to be complete HTML code rendered on the page before being served to the client (browser).

This clearly indicates we need to setup NodeServer, which can be called up by ASP.NET to get the VUEJS code rendered and added on ASPX page before it's being served to the Client (Browser). Please correct me If I am wrong. Here we are looking for a dynamic webages (Not the static one with prerendering or static generation)

We have started looking up for NUXT.JS as one of the options. But this is recommended to be used for the apps hosted for NodeServer.

> ref:[https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-Vue-starter/issues/67](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-Vue-starter)
>   [1](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-Vue-starter): https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-Vue-starter/issues/67

Other big challenge going with Nuxt is, they are likely launching Nuxt2.js version, which may or may not have breaking changes. https://medium.com/nuxt/nuxt-2-is-coming-oh-yeah-212c1a9e1a67

Next option is to looking for following:

- https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-Vue-starter
- [https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-Vue-starter)
- http://mgyongyosi.com/2016/Vuejs-server-side-rendering-with-aspnet-core/

Above links mentions using ASP.net core API Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.

I believe you must have faced this situation and reached to an optimal solution. I am looking for suggestions from veterans have achieved the same, what path to be followed?
IF this can be achieved at all? and what are the challenges I should look forward?

Thanks

Comment: If you do want migrating to VUEJS, go one step further to get rid of ASPX. That's why others chose ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Thanks Lex, will consider this option. We might be looking to keep ASPX since we are having some UserControls available over the page.